# Http request action Vs Invoke Http Request to call Graph api

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, power-automate

I want to initiate many api calls to graph api.. but not sure which connections we can use to do so inside our Power Automate flows, I find those 2 connections:-

1. Send HTTP Request, as follow:-

[image: johnjohnPter_2-1708088457750.png]

2. Invoke Http Request Preauthorized, as follow:-

[image: johnjohnPter_1-1708088307290.png]

so what are the differences between the 2 approaches? my main aim is to create a new Planner Plan, new Team Channel and show the Planner Plan as a tab inside the Team channel. so which action best suites my needs and why?

now for me, a found that if I use the Http request I will need to pass the authentication information, while for the Invoke Http request, I can get the authorization using the login in user.. so not sure what other differences are there?

Thanks

Comment: That is the main difference. Using the first one will involve quite a few steps to obtain the authentication token. The second one is all handled for your (or on behalf of the user).

Comment: @SamNseir so which is better or more suitable for calling graph api?

Comment: For sure the latter one, (with Entta).